Ida Pro shifted pointers not working
According to this article there is feature shifted pointers
I have pointer that points very far
*(_DWORD *)(myPointer + 0x10A33C)
*(_DWORD *)(myPointer + 0x10A340)
*(_DWORD *)(myPointer + 0x10A344)

if i go to Create new struct type... ida offers this struct with gap of 1,090,364 bytes.
struct struct_myPointer
{
  _BYTE gap0[1090364];
  _DWORD One;
  _DWORD Two
  _DWORD Three
};

This works great now in pseudocode it shows
myPointer->One = ...
myPointer->Two = ...
myPointer->Three = ...

However i wanted to learn approach with shifted pointers so i created following struct without gap.
struct struct_myPointer
{
  _DWORD One;
  _DWORD Two
  _DWORD Three
};

and inside pseudocode i changed Set lvar type... (hotkey Y) to
_BYTE *__shifted(struct_myPointer,1090364) myPointer

or
int *__shifted(struct_myPointer,1090364) myPointer

both give same result in pseudocode it shows variable as
ADJ(myPointer)[0x21467].one = ...
ADJ(myPointer)[0x21467].two = ...
ADJ(myPointer)[0x21468].three = ...

what's that square brackets [0x21467] how do i remove it entirely, no matter what offset used inSet lvar type... ida still shows the square brackets.
say i use _BYTE *__shifted(struct_myPointer,1) myPointer then ida shows [0x10A33] which is close to original offset.
What exactly is number in the square brackets and how to remove entirely remove square brackets using shifted pointers approach?
